# Trying to pass user input into string (C++)

Tags: c++, string, pass-by-reference

I am currently working on string and working on this simple example. I am trying to pass the *"birthdate"* user input into my *logSuccess* string when it is ptinted. Done a lot of googling but haven't found solution yet. Any tips?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

std::string birthdate;

void printString(const std::string& string)
{
   std::cout << string << std::endl;
}

void getBirthdate()
{
   std::cout<<"When is your birthday? "<<std::endl;
   cin>>birthdate;
}

int main()
{
std::string name = std::string("Dame") + " hello!";
std::string logSuccess = std::string("Thank you! We will send you a postcard on ") + birthdate;


printString(name);
getBirthdate();
printString(logSuccess);


std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Think about the *order* in which you do things! You have no loops, so the code in the `main` function will execute in a strict top-to-bottom direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
std::string logSuccess = std::string("Thank you! We will send you a postcard on ") + birthdate;
printString(name);
getBirthdate();
printString(logSuccess);
```

It should be:

```
string name = string("Dame") + " hello!";
string logSuccess = "Thank you! We will send you a postcard on " ;

printString(name);
getBirthdate();
logSuccess += birthdate;
printString(logSuccess);
```

Comment: Gotcha. Made the adjustment and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

At the time you create the message and assign it to logSuccess variable the birthdate variable is empty. You want to populate the logSuccess with data after you get the input from the user.

Comment: Oh okay so I just need to put the logSuccess variable/message after I declare my getBirtdate function then print the string

Comment: Exactly. You should still declare the variable at the beginning of the function as it's a good programming practice but append the birthdate to the logSuccess after taking the input.